# How can I get Rebol2 View running on Arch Linux?

Tags: x86, rebol, rebol2

There is a 64-bit version of Rebol2/Core available, but not of /View. If I try to execute the binary, it just says the file does not exist. What 32-bit libs do I need to install to get things running on Arch?

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out. All but one of the packages you need are in the official repos, and the other is available in the AUR, and can be installed with `yaourt`.

Install from the official repos (make sure you have the multilib repo enabled):

```
# pacman -S lib32-libx11 lib32-glibc lib32-ncurses lib32-libstdc++5 lib32-libxext lib32-freetype2 xorg-fonts-100dpi xorg-fonts-75dpi
```

Enable the AUR by adding this to `/etc/pacman.conf`:

```
[archlinuxfr]
SigLevel = Never
Server = http://repo.archlinux.fr/$arch
```

Run:

```
# pacman -Sy make yaourt fakeroot
```

Install the missing lib:

```
$ yaourt lib32-libxaw
```

Then reboot, and you're done!